# Serialize Map<String,Object> to Json and back

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I want to serialize a `Map<String,Object>` to JSON with Jackson and back. The object type can be of several beans. But when serializing back I think Jackson don't knows what type object has. Thus is serializes it to a `LinkedHashMa`p. Is it possible to add the information which type the object has?

Here is my sample program:

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {};

        ObjectMapper m  = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonFactory  jf = new JsonFactory();

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        UserBean bean1 = new UserBean();

        bean1.setId("1");
        bean1.setName("test");

        map.put("user", bean1);

        String test = m.writeValueAsString(map);

        map = m.readValue(test, typeRef);

        for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            final String key = entry.getKey();

             if (key.matches("user"))
             {
                final UserBean userBean = (UserBean)map.get(key);
             }
        }
```

---

```
public class UserBean {
    String id;
    String name;

     public UserBean()
     {
         super();
     }

     public void setId(String id){
         this.id = id;
     }

     public String getId(){
         return this.id;
     }

     public void setName(String name){
         this.name = name;
     }

     public String getName(){
         return this.name;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the map like below;

```
Map<String, UserBean> map = new HashMap<String, UserBean>();
```

(If Java 7 you can use use the diamond operator without specifying the types like new HashMap<>()).

You could also try using `@JsonDeserialize` using [jackson-annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

but the object can also be of another type differen from UserBean (e.g. AppBean). Then Jackson does not know which type the object has.

So if the key is "App" then i want to cast it to AppBean.